# Kusto KQL equivalent to with clause

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to find an alternative to MySQL (v8) with clause.

I have some long query that uses with clause for aliasing some result.

```
with top5 as (
        SELECT ....
) 
SELECT .... from top5 
UNION ALL .... from top5
```

I'm trying to find the equivalent to with clause in Kusto KQL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for `let` bounded to a tabular result set:

```
let Top5 = StormEvents | top 5 by StartTime;
Top5
| union StormEvents
| take 10
```

You can also use the [as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/asoperator) operator, to name a sub query and use it later, for example:

```
MyLogTable  
| where type == "Event"
| as T
| where Name == "Start"
| join (
    T
    | where Name == "Stop"
) on ActivityId
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I was missing the fact that I had 2 new lines in between the definition of Top5, and the usage, and KQL didn't get that.

Comment: KQL is fine with whitespace and empty lines, you just need to make sure to select it in the editor. The editor auto-selection of the query text is based on empty line borders.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `let` statement is what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/letstatement#using-materialize-function